# Continue executer next extension of contexte after dial call

Tags: asterisk

I would like to continue executing the next extension of the below contexte after dial() call is answered.

```
[sondage-80]
 exten => 78767239,1,Answer(500)
 same => 2, Set(CHANNEL(language)=moore)
 same => 3, Dial(sip/2700, 20, G)
 same => 4,AGI(test.php,1612198672)
 same => 5,Hangup()
```

If Dial(sip/2700) is answered, continue immediately in the next extension at the 4 priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do like that. You can do something before connecting to caller by

```
b([[context^]exten^]priority[(arg1[^...][^argN])]): Before initiating an
outgoing call, 'Gosub' to the specified location using the newly created
channel.  The 'Gosub' will be executed for each destination channel.
```

Or you can transfer call to conference and do n-way calling

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-n-way-call-howto/

Answer (score 0):

As i know, G needs a target. So try...

```
same => 3, Dial(sip/2700, 20, G(4))
```

...then the caller goes after answering the call to priority 4 and callee to priority 4+1. So if you want the callee to go to the AGI then...

```
same => 4,Hangup() ; Hangup the caller and...
same => 5,AGI(test.php,1612198672) ; ...this is for callee
```

Comment: I have done this below, and it is ok. same => 3, Dial(sip/2700, 20, G(sondage-80^78767239^3))